# Insert space between two characters of the same field using sed

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, format

I’m trying to insert a space character « » in the middle of every two-character field of my file (in my case 00 or CC for example) in order to double the field into two fields, my field delimiter being a space.

I am looking for a bash solution but a python-3.x script could also do.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Powerful%20Python%20One-Liners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a regex work?

python's re module could help you with that. but something like

```py
import re

#searches for a word boundary, two characters and another boundary.
#replaces it by <firstchar><space><seconchar>
#for every occurence in the contentsoffile.
re.sub(r"\b(.)(.)\b",r"\1 \2",contentsoffile)
```

you could read the file with a simple

```py
with open("myfile.something","r") as f:
    contentsoffile = f.read()
```

Comment: In fact it added a space character with one column fields too, but i can deal with that for now